# Bunifu Dataviz adding Datalabels

Tags: c#, bunifu

I've researched and can't seem to find if adding Data Labels to Dataviz charts is possible. I haven't seen an example that actually shows them. Is this something that is even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

An example of adding a Y-axis label:

```
var datapoint = new Bunifu.DataViz.DataPoint(Bunifu.DataViz.BunifuDataViz._type.Bunifu_line);

datapoint.addLabely("SUN", r.Next(0, 100).ToString());
```

Comment: thanks , that i know how to do , I was wondering it there was a way to show that actual value of the datapoint itself like in your example would be generated randomly. Data Labels that same way that you can have them on an Excel chart for example.